# Create a bubble map with the size of the bubble indicating number of points in certain proximity

Tags: qgis

I made bubble maps before and usually with the size of the bubble indicating a certain variable value for that point. I have a dataset with point data with longitude and latitude. Now I want to create a bubble map but with the size of the bubble indicating the number of points in a grid cell of a certain size or in a predefined proximity. Attached I have put a picture that shows what I want to do. [image]

Is that possible in QGIS?

Comment: First, each question here should focus on one tool - if you want solutions for QGIS or R then ask two questions, one for each. Secondly: your input data is points scattered over a grid, then you want to calculate points in each grid cell, then draw "bubbles" (circles?) centred on what? The grid?

Comment: @Spacedman, sorry for a bit of a vague question. I have basically point data with latitude and longitude.  I will edit the question as well.

Comment: So are the bubbles just circles, and their centres are on the grid cell coordinates? So its a regular grid of circles of different sizes?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to provide clarity in response to requests for clarification. A graphic explaining you goal would help.

Comment: Hey, I edited it and made a simple illustration showing what I would like to do, I hope it is clear now!

Comment: Where should the centre of the bubble be? In the middle of the grid cell? Or at the centroid of the points in the grid cell?

Answer (score 2):

### Basic use for a grid:

Add a geometry generator style to your grid and enter the expression `centroid($geometry)`:

[image]

Or simply use the centroid fill style.

Choose the marker symbol and select data defined override:

[image]

Open the expression builder or the assistant. Enter the expression `array_length(overlay_contains('Name of your point layer',$id))`. Choose the settings as you like.

[image]

### Hint: This way you cannot see a legend. So I suggest to misuse pie diagrams.

Navigate to Diagrams, choose Pie Chart and then navigate to Size. Choose scaled size and enter the expression `array_length(overlay_contains('Name of your point layer',$id))`. Click Find and set up the size and style as you like:

[image]

Then navigate to Legend, click on the button and set up the legend as you like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a "New virtual layer", using "Layer->Create Layer->New virtual layer...".

Then add two layers of your own using the "Import" button by renaming my layer names to your own and run this script see figure 1:

[image]

Figure 1

```
WITH tbla AS (SELECT count(*) cnt, ST_Centroid(ST_Union(a.geometry)) c_geom from "centr_buf" a
              JOIN "polygon_grid_cel" b ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry) group by b.geometry)
SELECT cnt, ST_Buffer(c_geom, cnt*0.04) geom_varbyffer FROM tbla;
```

2. See figure 2 for the result.

[image]

Figure 2

If necessary, adjust the required sizes of your bubbles and save the result of the temporary layer to a file.